# How to access the iPhone's camera from Mobile Safari

Tags: iphone

Is there a API or way for accessing the the iPhone's camera from Mobile Safari?I want to create a application that can read barcode within the browser.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There's no way to do that. No web page can access internal devices.

You can do however a small tiny app that its launched via mobile safari link and makes user select the barcode image and then redirect to a web page that will process (the small app will also upload). Like what [THIS](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-photo-picker/) guys actually implemented (the link provides code).

If you doesn't have experience with Objective C and Cocoa Touch you can create that app via [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) like if you were creating a Web Page.

**UPDATE**

From iOS 6 and so on you actually can as the [official specs says](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/), you can use it via the upload API as [seen here](http://agileleague.com/2012/10/hidden-gem-of-ios6-file-uploads-in-mobile-safari/).

Comment: This answer is outdated; see the other answers.

Comment: @forresto Updated. I totally forgot this answer.

Comment: Can you do this with the rear camera? How? I was thinking about using WebRTC.

Answer (score 7):

It's now supported in iOS 6. I believe it uses a regular form file input field.

You can see [some explanation here](http://www.everythingicafe.com/ios-6-supports-file-uploads-via-safari/2012/06/15/).

Answer (score 4):

Try using input tag `<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture/>.`

It works well as compared to getUserMedia method which is fully supported by Opera mobile and chrome higher versions.
Hope it help.