# HTML File Chooser on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Can we access the iOS camera roll using the Safari's file chooser i.e. `<input type="file">`? According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6827873/583539), we cannot access the camera.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Safari doesn't support file uploading. You can, however, purchase and install iCab, which does.