# How to access my computer's camera in a desktop Safari web application

Tags: javascript, safari, camera, cross-browser

I'm working on a web application and I need to be able to access my computer's camera in Safari much like Firefox and Chrome are able to through the use of getUserMedia.  What is Safari's way of handling native camera access when on a desktop?  Do I need to use flash or can I use html/javascript?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=getusermedia

Comment: I know getUserMedia is not supported by Safari.  That does not solve my problem.  I need to know how to access the camera in Safari since getUserMedia does not work.

Comment: Are you looking to actually take video or pictures, or do you just want to upload video or pictures? Related: [How to access the iPhone's camera from Mobile Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827873/how-to-access-the-iphones-camera-from-mobile-safari) (though it is geared towards Safari on iOS.

Comment: I'm looking to take a picture, not just upload one which has already been saved on my computer.  That link you provided is great for mobile safari but does nothing for Safari running on a computer

Comment: Have you solved this problem?